# iPad 6.1.2 Supporting Xcode Version

Tags: xcode4.6

Hi Friends i am using Xcode version 6.1 and my iPad iOS version is 6.1.2 my problem is i am not able to run the application directly in iPad.
  i am not able to debug the application using device please tell me which Xcode version is matched iOS 6.1.2 please tell me. and one more problem is i am deploy the app using Ad_Hoc certificate but app is not installed. i don't the problem if you know any one please let me know.

Comment: I have the same problem, don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You have two separate questions here so you are less likely to get an answer for either. Firstly, there is no Xcode version 6.1, make sure you have the latest Xcode version (currently 4.6.1 . Secondly, there are many, many possible reasons why an app won't install. Once you have the latest version of Xcode, say exactly what error message you are receiving. Try to ask one question, get an answer and accept it before you ask another. You will get more help from others this way